# compiled php 5.2 with php-fpm doesn't work properly

Tags: php, apache, compilation, debian

I maintain a server for a company and we will migrate their old server (debian 6) to a new one (debian 8). Unfortunatly their websites are coded with php 5.2.
So to be able to use them properly, I've compiled php 5.2 with some patches. The patches allow the use of php-fpm even if it's not natively integrated with php 5.2.

After installing this new php, I set up my apache config like this:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/website

    <Directory /var/www/webtsite/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
            AllowOverride all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/opt/php52/var/run/website.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunatly it doesn't work and I have the error: "No input file specified"

After some researches I found another solution by changing the FilesMatch with this:

```
    Alias /virtualpath /var/www/website
    FastCgiExternalServer /var/www -socket /opt/php52/var/run/website.sock
    AddHandler php-fcgi .php
    Action php-fcgi /virtualpath
```

But now, my website is in php 5.2 but doesn't load CSS...
(Those solutions refer to this post: [php-fpm apache2 403 error on .css .js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827527/php-fpm-apache2-403-error-on-css-js-files) )

So my question, how can php 5.2 properly ? 
I don't know if the website can properly work with php 5.3 or more.

Thank you for your help !